# Is there a way of enabling VBA events within an event if they are already disabled

Tags: excel, vba, events

I suspect the answer is a clear no as it is a circular argument

But...

I export a report from a software package directly into an existing Excel workbook. The software package creates a new sheet in Excel and populates the sheet.  By default the new sheet is called Sheet1.  It is a large report and within the Excel workbook there is a Workbook_SheetChange event.  Every cell of the exported report updates individually in Excel and so every cell runs the SheetChange event.  This increases the import time 10 fold.

I can add, to the SheetChange event, the following

if Sh.name = "Sheet1" then exit sub

This speeds up the import process beautifully but of course no events will ever fire again because I have disabled them.  So the workbook macros are then unusable.

I want to be able to add application.enableEvents = true when the Sheet1 worksheet is deactivated but of course this will not fire because events have already been disabled.

I could add a button that must be pressed that will trigger re-enabling via a module sub but it's not particularly intuitive to expect the user to have to do this. Also there are other events that may need to fire before the user presses it so they would be missed.

Therefore, my stupid question is -  Is there another way to re enable events?

I could, I suppose, have a Worksheet_Change event in every worksheet rather than a global Workbook_SheetChange event but thought I'd ask before I do this.

thanks

Comment: how do you export the report into existing excel workbook? is it via a VBA code?

Comment: No unfortunately not.  It's directly from within the other software by clicking a button from within it and selecting the workbook you want to export to

Comment: then have it export to a brand new workbook and once it's done, write a simple VBA code to import it in your workbook. In this 2nd step you will set `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the very beginning and `Application.EnableEvents = True`  at the end

Comment: Yes that would work.  I think on balance I'll just move the event to a Worksheet_Change event for each sheet , from the Workbook_SheetChange, as it would be a re education of 500 users to tell them to export to a new book rather an existing.  thanks for your efforts

Comment: It could be transparent to the 500 users: they would open the "usual" workbook, your macro would fire at Workbook_Open() event and import from the "temporary" worksheet into its sheet1. Nobody would notice that.

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility.  I'll chat to my team and see what they think.  many thanks

Comment: Why won't any event fire again if you use `if Sh.name = "Sheet1" then exit sub`? Because you have disabled events at the beginning of the `Workbook_SheetChange` event? tbh I don't know the impact of an event firing so I guess it still would be too slow if you entered and immediately exited the event sub for every change on `sheet1`?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have the importer control Events.
Just have the import sub:

1. disable Events
2. import to create *Sheet1*
3. re-enable Events once *Sheet1* is complete.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately the other software controls the export.  you click a button within it and select the workbook you want to export to.

Comment: @MrPea  Then **you** must disable Events before you click that button.

Comment: if it was just me then yes,  but there's circa 500 users that use the process so to educated them all to disable before export wouldn't be an option unfortunately.  I think I'm just going to move the event to each of the specific worksheets.  thanks for your time

Comment: @MrPea  that is a reasonable approach